# OpenGL project is requiring DirectX lib files

Tags: c++, opengl, directx

I have glut version 3.7 installed, running Windows 7 and using VS 2010:

[image: Screenshot]

I seem unable to run any C++ programs without it saying it requires Direct X libraries and includes in the VC++ Directories properties tab.
Under propertes>input>additional dependencies it shows dxerr.lib and a few other dx libraries under inherited values which I believe is the cause of this error. How can I remove these values? Unless anyone believes the error originates elsewhere...

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <GL\glut.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);   
    glutInitWindowSize(720, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("First OpenGL Project");   
    return 1;
}
```

> > Error    1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'dxerr.lib' c:\Users\mallaboro\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\First OpenGL Project2\First OpenGL Project2\LINK   First OpenGL Project2

Comment: Your screenshot shows the directories only. What is configured in the Linker settings? Note that "LNK1104" indicates, that the error might be there...

Comment: Nothing as far as I'm aware. I started a new project, added directories to VC++ Directories. I've done a lot of direct x work before and might have set it somewhere along the line to automatically include some dx11 libraries in linker, which would explain why these are automatically included in Additional Dependencies "dxerr.lib;d3d11.lib;d3dx11.lib;d3dcompiler.lib;"

Comment: Well - there you are. As far as I understand the VS-Compiler, those Dependencies will be looked for, even if they are not needed. You might be able to compile if you remove those Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Ye, but I don't appear to be able to remove them as they're in the list of inherited values.

Comment: Where exactly did you acquire "glut version 3.1" and/or the `glut-3.6` directory?  1997 is *terrifyingly* old.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php. Was mistaken, I'm using 3.6, got it here

Answer (score 0):

Try a [maintained GLUT implementation](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) instead of nearly twenty-year-old software.